# How can I implement a counter that enforces a quota in javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I've made a quick and dirty schedule in javascript, that is only going to be used on the local intranet here.  Basically, it has a bunch of radio buttons with the different shifts available, and when you click submit, it saves to a .txt file in the default download directory.  What i need is to be able to limit each shift to 110 max employees, as that is all the seats that we have.  is there an easy way to implement this with javascript?  or will i need to go with another solution?  Thanks in advance

```
   <html>
   <head>

<script language="Javascript" >
function download(filename, text) {
  var pom = document.createElement('a');
  pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 

encodeURIComponent(text));
  pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

  pom.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(pom);

  pom.click();

  document.body.removeChild(pom);
}

function addTextTXT()
{
    document.addtext.name.value = document.addtext.name.value + ".txt"
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="addtext" onsubmit="download(this['uid'].value, this['name'].value+this['m1'].value+this['m2'].value+this['tu1'].value+this['tu2'].value+this['w1'].value+this['w2'].value+this['th1'].value+this['th2'].value+this['f1'].value+this['f2'].value+this['sa1'].value+this['sa2'].value+this['su1'].value+this['su2'].value)" />
<P> Monday&emsp;Tuesday&emsp;Wednesday&emsp;Thursday&emsp;Friday&emsp;Saturday&emsp;Sunday
<br><input type="radio" name="m1" value=", m1 3-9," id="Monday1" />3-9 &emsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="tu1" value="tu1 3-9," id="Tuesday1" /> 3-9 &emsp;&emsp; <input type="radio" name="w1" value="w1 3-9," id="Wednesday1" />3-9 &emsp;&emsp; <input type="radio" name="th1" value="th1 3-9," id="Thursday1" />3-9 &emsp; <input type="radio" name="f1" value="f1 3-9," id="Friday1" />3-9 &emsp; <input type="radio" name="sa1" value="sa1 10-5," id="Saturday1" />10-5 &emsp; <input type="radio" name="su1" value="su1 1-9," id="Sunday1" />1-9 &emsp;  
            <br><input type="radio" name="m1" value="m1 5-9," id="Monday1" />5-9 &emsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="tu1" value="tu1 5-9," id="Tuesday1" /> 5-9 &emsp;&emsp; <input type="radio" name="w1" value="w1 5-9," id="Wednesday1" />5-9 &emsp;&emsp; <input type="radio" name="th1" value="th1 5-9," id="Thursday1" />5-9 &emsp; <input type="radio" name="f1" value="f1 5-9," id="Friday1" />5-9
            <br><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="m1" value="m1 Off," id="Monday1" />Off &emsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="tu1" value="tu1 Off," id="Tuesday1" /> Off &emsp;&emsp; <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="w1" value="w1 Off," id="Wednesday1" />Off &emsp;&emsp; <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="th1" value="th1 Off," id="Thursday1" />Off &emsp; <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="f1" value="f1 Off," id="Friday1" />Off &emsp; <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="sa1" value="sa1 Off," id="Saturday1" />Off &emsp; <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="su1" value="su1 Off," id="Sunday1" />Off &emsp;
<br>
<P> Monday&emsp;Tuesday&emsp;Wednesday&emsp;Thursday&emsp;Friday&emsp;Saturday&emsp;Sunday
<br><input type="radio" name="m2" value="m2 3-9," id="Monday2" />3-9 &emsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="tu2" value="tu2 3-9," id="Tuesday2" /> 3-9 &emsp;&emsp; <input type="radio" name="w2" value="w2 3-9," id="Wednesday2" />3-9 &emsp;&emsp; <input type="radio" name="th2" value="th2 3-9," id="Thursday2" />3-9 &emsp; <input type="radio" name="f2" value="f2 3-9," id="Friday2" />3-9 &emsp; <input type="radio" name="sa2" value="sa2 10-5," id="Saturday2" />10-5 &emsp; <input type="radio" name="su2" value="su2 1-9," id="Sunday2" />1-9 &emsp;  
            <br><input type="radio" name="m2" value="m2 5-9," id="Monday2" />5-9 &emsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="tu2" value="tu2 5-9," id="Tuesday2" /> 5-9 &emsp;&emsp; <input type="radio" name="w2" value="w2 5-9," id="Wednesday2" />5-9 &emsp;&emsp; <input type="radio" name="th2" value="th2 5-9," id="Thursday2" />5-9 &emsp; <input type="radio" name="f2" value="f2 5-9," id="Friday2" />5-9
            <br><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="m2" value="m2 Off," id="Monday2" />Off &emsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" checked="checked" name="tu2" value="tu2 Off," id="Tuesday2" /> Off &emsp;&emsp; <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="w2" value="w2 Off," id="Wednesday2" />Off &emsp;&emsp; <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="th2" value="th2 Off," id="Thursday2" />Off &emsp; <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="f2" value="f2 Off," id="Friday2" />Off &emsp; <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="sa2" value="sa2 Off," id="Saturday2" />Off &emsp; <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="su2" value="su2 Off" id="Sunday2" />Off &emsp;
<P><input type="text" name="uid" value="" placeholder="ID Number"><input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Interviewer Name">
<input type="submit" onClick="addTexttxt();" value="Save As TXT">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 1):

Since the file will be stored in each person's local file system, your page can't know the total from other people's machines. You will need to store the file/data on a server and then that single file can be checked (with an AJAX call) before a new person can sign up for a shift.

A simple server-side language is .php, which most servers either already support or you can install yourself.

Comment: So the thought is, since we use thin clients to RDP to a single static image, to host the script on that.  what i'm wondering is if i'm going about this the right way, or should i be looking for a different solution?  Another idea we had kicked around was to have a simple kiosk machine, that everyone would use.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention the RDP to a single image. That's different. In that case, your approach should work.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, there's quite a lot going on here today, and i've been given a deadline of tonight to have this up and going in a small scale alpha.  that and we have a job closing today and the stress level is a little higher than normal.  So with my approach, it is possible to implement a counter or a quota of some sort?